# Reseting responses in a GoogleDocs Form

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I want to reuse a GoogleDocs Form, with (almost) the same Form, but with fresh Responses.

I did copy it, but I don't know how to reset responses (not reseting the form itself, i.e. `Form/Delete Form`).

I manually erased the previous entries. However, they are still treated as entries with values set to `''`.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get a 'fresh' form by deleting the entry *rows*. That is, select the entire row by clicking the row number(s), right-click, and choose *Delete row*.

([source](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/UOhsnw0V3cc/tyIDD2NL3TsJ))

I just did the following test case:

1. Create a simple form
2. Submit a response
3. In the spreadsheet, select the response row, right-click, delete row
4. Submit a new response

Result: The second response posted in #4 is listed on the first row. The response summary shows only one response.

Comment: Thanks. I just saw that there is a difference between `Delete rows` and erasing their content (quite counterintuitive, though).